# How to insert a margin at the right and left of the page?

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to insert this margin, but I don't know why... I want it to be like  [Twitter](http://twitter.com) or TwitPic

My CSS:

```
 body {
        margin: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #edece9;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Verdana";
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #333;
      }
```

Comment: the code you pasted could not be understood, use code tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a page structure like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then **style.css** should look like:

```
* {margin:0;}
div#main {
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

twitter uses a fixed-width div which uses `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto`. this will center the div horizontally

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a div with a fixed with (your desired page width and put its `margin:0 auto`